# Subquery returning more than one result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am still fairly new to SQL and the stored procedure I recently created keeps telling me that a subquery is returning more than one result but I can't figure out which one is the problem. If anyone has a moment and can tell me what I am missing, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks!

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.customer_no [id],
        x.esal1_desc [constituent],
        a.perf [activity],
        a.sp_act_dt [activity_date],
        c.description[activity_type],
        d.display_name_tiny [solicitor],
        s.description [status],
        ISNULL(a.num_attendees,0)[attending],
        a.notes [notes],
        e.address [email]
FROM   [dbo].t_special_activity a
        left outer join [dbo].tr_special_activity_status s ON s.id = a.status
        left outer join [dbo].tr_special_activity c ON c.id = a.sp_act
        left outer JOIN [dbo].FT_CONSTITUENT_DISPLAY_NAME() d ON a.worker_customer_no = d.customer_no
        left outer JOIN [dbo].T_EADDRESS e on a.customer_no=e.customer_no and primary_ind='Y'
        left outer JOIN [dbo].TX_CUST_SAL x on a.customer_no=x.customer_no and default_ind='Y'
WHERE a.status IN (ISNULL(@status, (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM TR_SPECIAL_ACTIVITY_STATUS)))  
    AND a.sp_act_dt BETWEEN (ISNULL(@activity_start,(SELECT MIN(sp_act_dt) FROM T_SPECIAL_ACTIVITY))) 
        AND (ISNULL(@activity_end,(SELECT MAX(sp_act_dt) FROM T_SPECIAL_ACTIVITY)))
    AND ((ISNULL(@list,0) = 0) OR EXISTS (SELECT customer_no FROM T_LIST_CONTENTS lc WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE a.customer_no = lc.customer_no and lc.list_no = @list))
```

Comment: I'm sure `SELECT DISTINCT id FROM TR_SPECIAL_ACTIVITY_STATUS` return more than 1 row.

Comment: `(ISNULL(@status, (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM TR_SPECIAL_ACTIVITY_STATUS)))` is where you're getting that error. Can't really tell you what to do until I know more about how @status is generated

Answer (score 2):

Alas, you cannot use this expression:

```
WHERE a.status IN (ISNULL(@status, (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM TR_SPECIAL_ACTIVITY_STATUS)))
```

The subquery is in a place where a single value is expected.  In any case, I think you want:

```
WHERE @status IS NULL OR
      a.status IN (SELECT id FROM TR_SPECIAL_ACTIVITY_STATUS)
```

Note that `select distinct` is irrelevant in an `IN` clause.  At best it does nothing; at worst it impedes the optimizer.

I realize this is a little confusing.  You are thinking that `IN` takes a list -- and the list could even be a subquery.  But, the elements of the list are *scalars* not *lists*.  So, when a subquery is an *element* of the list, then it is assumed to be a single value.

Comment: Ahh...that makes sense...Still trying to make the transfer from C# into SQL and realizing that sometimes my logic doesn't compute properly...Thank you!